# Apply the styles to selected values in the multi-select dropdown in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ngselect

I am new to angular. As part of my baby steps , I have a ng-select(multiple)component.

this is my component.html

```
     <label>Multiselect with custom bindings</label>
    <ng-select [multiple]=true>
    <ng-option *ngFor= "let city of cities" [value]="city.id"> {{city.name}}</ng-option>
    </ng-select>
```

component.ts

```
cities = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Vilnius' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Kaunas' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Pavilnys' },
{ id: 4, name: 'Pabradė' },
{ id: 5, name: 'Klaipėda' },
];
```

[image: Screenshot of dropdown as of now]

I have custom component called tags which styles the selected values.

```
<tags [(ng-model)]="values" </tags>
```

My query is I need to pass these selected values to this component and  display the styled selected values in the same place .  Please help!. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the selected values to the component:

component.ts:

```
selectedValues = [];
```

component.html:
add the following to your ng-select:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedValues"
```

It will automatically update this array.
Then you can display the array data again where you need them.

Not sure if this answers your question. What do you mean by 'display the styled selected values in the same place'?